# Adding an image to a custom info window android google maps api

Tags: android, api, maps

I'm trying to add a 20 unique images to 20 different custom info windows. But all of the images appear to be the same when I run the program.

```
map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter(){

  @Override
  public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

  View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custommarker, null);
  LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.ll);

  ImageView title = new ImageView(this);
  title.setImage(Bitmap);
  ll.addView(title);   



  return v;

}

 @Override
 public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
    return null;        
}                                     
});
```